# Redirect to old images folder, from new "root" folder

Tags: .htaccess

### STATUS

The client has a site visible at client-domain.com, inside the root there is an .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !v2/.*

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v2/$1 [L]
```

...and some folders:

- v0 (with a page for temporary shoutdown the server)
- v1 first version
- v2 actual version of website

### GOAL

Create a new website on v3, but keeping some asssets of version v2

(there is a big folder with subfolders in client-domain.com/assets/prjimg/  that obviously pointing at  root/v2/assets/prjimg.
I can't move the folder, I don't have ssh access... I'd like to add a line to the new .htaccess without create a mess for pointing on v3 the website but v2 all the link at that subfolder 'prjimg')

> - All website --> root/v3/
> - but /assets/prjimg --> root/v2/asstes/prjimg

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !v3/.*

*** something here? ***

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ v3/$1 [L]
```

I look for but doesn't find yet the solution, sometimes 500 eorr, sometimes loop...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# /assets/prjimg/ goes to /v2/
RewriteRule ^assets/prjimg(/.*)?$ v2/$0 [L,NC]

# everything else goes to /v3/
RewriteRule !^(v2|v3)/ v3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```